# Find listBox name or typeOf object in WPF C# drag & drop

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, listbox, observablecollection

I'm writing an app where i can drag from one list to another one, but i can also drag from the same list to itself. Is there anyway to know which list is the source list (I mean which list i dragged from) or what data i dragged?
I have 2 lists: lbTwo and lbOne, and two datas (one for each list of ObservableCollection): firstDataType and secondDataType.
The only way i found to get the data is (But i prefer to get the list name and not the data it contains):

```
 private void ListBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
            ListBox parent = (ListBox)sender;

            string data_type = (e.Data.GetFormats())[0];
 }
```

but it's not really elegant and i also get the whole name (Myapp.firstDataType).

Thanks!!

Comment: Bad Advice - But in the xaml add Name for both the listboxes and then in the code test for Control.Name.

Comment: I already gave the listBoxes names... but there is no option for Control.Name... (No such variable)

Comment: By Control.Name - what I meant was - In your above code it will be parent.Name.

Comment: Thanks, i found the dragSource.Name do the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how my code looks like:

Xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="LeftBox" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Common_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
             AllowDrop="True"
             Drop="Common_Drop"/>
    <ListBox Name="RightBox" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="Common_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
             AllowDrop="True"
             Drop="Common_Drop"/>
```

I call this method to load test data into my Listboxes:

```
private void LoadData()
    {
        var lstbox1Data = new string[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
        var lstbox2Data = new string[] { "Alpha", "Beta", "Theta", "Gamma", "Phi" };

        foreach (var item in lstbox1Data)
        {
            LeftBox.Items.Add(item);
        }

        foreach (var item in lstbox2Data)
        {
            RightBox.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

This is the actual implementation of DragDrop across Listboxes & re-arrange within Listbox.

```
    private void Common_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var destLisBox = sender as ListBox;
        var dragDropData = e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragDropData)) as DragDropData;

        if (dragDropData != null)
        {
            var dataWhereToInsert = GetDataFromListBox(destLisBox, e.GetPosition(destLisBox));

            if (dataWhereToInsert != null)
            {
                var insertAtIndex = destLisBox.Items.IndexOf(dataWhereToInsert);
                if (insertAtIndex >= 0)
                {
                    dragDropData.DragStartSource.Items.Remove(dragDropData.ActualData);
                    destLisBox.Items.Insert(insertAtIndex, dragDropData.ActualData);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dragDropData.DragStartSource.Items.Remove(dragDropData.ActualData);
                destLisBox.Items.Add(dragDropData.ActualData);
            }
        }
    }   

    private static object GetDataFromListBox(ListBox source, Point point)
    {
        UIElement element = source.InputHitTest(point) as UIElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            object data = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            while (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                data = source.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(element);
                if (data == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
                {
                    element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as UIElement;
                }
                if (element == source)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            if (data != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
            {
                return data;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void Common_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var srcListBox = sender as ListBox;
        if (srcListBox != null)
        {
            var data = GetDataFromListBox(srcListBox, e.GetPosition(srcListBox));

            if (data != null)
            {
                var dragDropData = new DragDropData
                {
                    ActualData = data,
                    DragStartSource = srcListBox
                };

                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(srcListBox, dragDropData, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that I wrapped the data & sender into below class:

```
public class DragDropData
{
    public object ActualData { get; set; }
    public ListBox DragStartSource { get; set; }
}
```

That amazing : GetDataFromListBox method comes from:
[http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/drag-and-drop-item-in-listbox-in-wpf/]

Comment: Thanks, that works well!
Do you have any idea how can i add an visual indicator so i can see where i drop it.?

Comment: @Ben - I dont have any experience doing that - may be this can help: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2007/07/12/drag-amp-drop-in-wpf-explained-end-to-end/